# CompareTo() method of short in C#

Tags: c#, compare, short

I want to use `CompareTo()` method in C#. When I use it with `long` and `int` data types the comare result is *always* `-1, 0, 1`.
What about data type `short`? When I compare two values (less than, greater than) the result is *always* a value *depending* on the compared given values but **not** `-1, 0, 1`.

I use .Net Framework, not .Net Code.

Comment: The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int16.compareto?view=netframework-4.8) is quite clear. "Less than zero: The instance is less than `value`", "Zero: The instance is equal to `value`", "Greater than zero: The instance is greater than `value`"

Answer (score 3):

These *implementation details* are for *performance*. Note, that `CompareTo` must return just *negative*, *positive* or *zero* values say, `-123`, `456`, `0`; not necessary `-1`, `1`, `0`.

Now let's have a look at implementations. For `Short` (and `Byte`) we can just *subtract* and that's enough:

```
// Pseudocode
CompareTo() => a - b;
```

For instance

```
(short)456 - (short)123 == 333 > 0 // so 456 > 123
 (byte)5 - (byte)7      ==  -2 < 0 // so   5 < 7
```

What's going on? In case of `short` type, values are in `[short.MinValue..short.MaxValue]` range, i.e. `[-32768..32767]`; when we subtract these values they will be *cast* into `int`. Note, that we are *guaranteed* for not having **integer overflow**:

```
-32768 - 32767  == -65535 // min possible value, which is > int.MinValue
 32767 - -32768 ==  65535 // max possible value, which is < int.MaxValue
```

When we have `int` or `long` to compare we *can't* just subtract; here's a *counter example*:

```
int.MinValue - 1 == some positive number! It means that MinValue > 1
```

and we have to *compare*

```
// Pseudocode
CompareTo() => 
    a == b ? 0
  : a < b ? - 1
  : 1;
```